# How to respond_to PNG or JPG in Rails and generate image from HTML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, image-generation, responders

I am looking for a gem or solution to generate image in controller response.

It would be nice if it's possible to do in controller like that:

```
respond_to :html, :png

def show
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.png { ??? }  # some html to png converter 
  end
end
```

When the `png` format is requested the response handles with template:

```
#show.png.haml
%h1
  Some title
%p
  Some content
```

The result should be an image.

I know about `pdf` generation solutions [PDFKit](https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit), [prawn](https://github.com/sandal/prawn) and am looking for image generation.

Does anybody know working solution/example? Any starting point would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out here: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2006/12/19/using-custom-mime-types

```
Mime::Type.register "image/png", :png

# then in your controller action
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { }
    format.png { }
  end
end
```

**UPD**

What about image generating. If you need to convert your HTML page into image. You can use `wkhtmltoimage`
http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/detail?name=wkhtmltoimage-0.10.0_beta2-static-amd64.tar.bz2&can=4&q=

There is no gem like `pdfkit` for `wkhtmltopdf` but it is easy to use.

Also you can use `pdfKIT` gem and after that convert PDF to PNG with imagemagick. That is quite easy too.

**UPD**

Istead of using `SnapShot` I prefer to use `IMGKit` gem

https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit

Comment: @floor, thanks for response. My bad, I was not very clear with my question. The question was more about image generation from html. Now I clarified it.

Comment: You need to convert your html to image? look upate

Comment: thanks again. There is a gem for `wkhtmltopdf`: https://github.com/siuying/websnap. And here is an example http://www.freezzo.com/2010/07/29/how-to-create-pdfs-and-images-from-your-website-in-rails/