# Capture screenshots for a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, screenshot

I have a Rails app that I want to capture a screenshot of a webpage when the user enters a url.

1. Is it possible to do this in Rails (is there any gem that would do this?)
2. If not, are there any reliable services that generate *live* screenshots

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use IMGKit gem for that: https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit

Related topic: [How to respond_to PNG or JPG in Rails and generate image from HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135666/how-to-respond-to-png-or-jpg-in-rails-and-generate-image-from-html)

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this only works for HTML with inlined CSS, and no javascript is executed. You can use a gem like `premailer` to inline your CSS, but the results aren't great.

Answer (score 6):

[ScreenCap](https://github.com/maxwell/screencap) gem which uses PhantomJS under the hood. Grab whole pages or just specific divs, or even exact x y coordinates.

Comment: Is there a way to allow the user to capture a screen-shot of their page with this gem after they have logged in?

Comment: @Ctpelnar1988 Yes, the gem has the ability to fill out login form fields like username and password, e.g. `fill_in 'Username or Email', :with => 'user@example.com'`

Comment: gem 'screencap' is based on PhantomJS which is discontinued = so no longer viable solution

Answer (score 2):

I have used [`GrabzIt`](https://github.com/cavneb/grabz_it) for this. This is quite simple.