# I want to get a screenshot of a website in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

In my Rails app user enters the web address. I want to display only the home page of the given url as a image into my rails app.
It it there any way to do this?
Is there any gem present for that?

Comment: You can use phantomjs. 

https://github.com/colszowka/phantomjs-gem
http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647632/capture-screenshots-for-a-ruby-on-rails-application